# Video Quality Difference on Camera and PC

Tags: video, camera, hardware, lcd, television

I have a video file on my Canon Camera. When i diretly connect it to TV via HDMI, video quality is so high. But when i copy that file to PC and watch in on same TV screen, video quality decrease. TV screen is full HD and both connection is HDMI. How can his happen?

Note: PC use same TV as screen also.

Comment: It is possible the video is being compressed as you transfer it to the PC - do you know the format, duration and file size of the video on the PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple.

Canon cameras, like most video-specific devices are tuned for image quality.
Computers try to output accurate images with minimal processing ( unless you use specific tools for it )

What you see is completely natural and not an issue.
It's actually pretty software/implementation specific

Comment: But i mean camera output is better. When i put video on PC, quality decrase on same TV screen.

Comment: camera is tuned for display of images and video, it probably does post-processing on things that it displays on the screen. your computer does not - it tries to display the images closer to the source file ( i.e. without image enhancements / quality improvement before display )